# Подскажите как добавить линию точек между текстом?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как добавить линию точек между текстом?

```css
.item {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 17px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.item > div {
    padding: 6px 0;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Материал</div><div>Сосна</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Материал</div><div>Сосна</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS. без изменения текущего `html`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113982/discussion-on-question-by-sergey-mironov------).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно было бы так:

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding: 5px;
}

.space_underline-dashed {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="item">
    <span>Материал</span>
    <span class="space_underline-dashed"></span>
    <span>Сосна</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>Материал</span>
    <span class="space_underline-dashed"></span>
    <span>Сосна</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но, если разрешается изменять только стили, тогда:

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font: 14px/1.22 sans-serif;
}

.item>div {
  padding: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item>div:nth-child(odd) {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
}
.item>div:nth-child(odd)::after {
  content: '\00a0';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-73%);
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 6px;
  font: inherit;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Материал</div>
    <div>Сосна</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Инструменты</div>
    <div>Молоток</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с использованием `background: linear-gradient`

```css
.item {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 17px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.item > div {
    padding: 6px 0;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.item > div:first-child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.item > div:first-child::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, 
    transparent 1px,
    #000 1px) repeat-x 0 0 / 2px auto;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Материал</div><div>Сосна</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Материал</div><div>Сосна</div>
  </div>
</div>
```